# Technique or exercise to play this part from a song which i'm stuck with

Tags: technique, electric-guitar, practice

I want to play this part but i'm stuck on how to play this correctly and efficiently with my fingers. Any technique or exercise related to this is welcomed. BTW, the song is 'That was Just your life by Metallica.

```
    e|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    B|-15h17p15p12-15h17p15p12-15h17p15p12-15h17p15p12-15h17p15p12-15h17p15p12-|
    G|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    D|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    A|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    E|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 8):

*the basic fragment is just using hammerons and pulloffs.*

have your first finger on the 12th fret, 3rd on the 15th and 4th on the 17th.

Play the 15 with your 3rd finger, hammeron to 17 with pinkie, pulloff to 15, then pulloff to 12.

the way to practice this baby is to get a [metronome](http://www.metronomeonline.com/) and slooooooow it down.  I assume the rhythm is straight 16th notes but whatever it is, make sure that at a slow speed you articulate every note.  Go so slow that it's boring(it has a purpose).

After playing perfectly say 10 times in a row, up the metronome 8bpm and repeat.  At some point your hands will likely get tired or you'll lose accuracy.  at this point back down 8 bpm, and try again.  If you hit your limit then good news, your fingers are ready to start recovering!!!  Give it a day and then try again, same technique.

This will push your speed up as best it can, without losing accuracy, or damaging your hands :)

Here's a related question I think might also help you out :):

[I find myself making the same mistake when practising - despite focussing on that part- how to remedy?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11407/i-find-myself-making-the-same-mistake-when-practising-despite-focussing-on-tha/11415#11415)